# Is it possible to let spring security list every available URL of a webapp and how it is secured?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm adding security to a spring MVC web application that has about 100 different urls you can access (for example: GET /users, GET /users/{userId}, ...).

I'm adding security with Spring Security's Method Security Expressions:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/load-configurations", produces = "application/json")
@PreAuthorize("@accessChecker.canViewBusinessData(authentication)")
public ResponseEntity<List<SavedCalculationConfiguration>> loadConfigurations() {
```

and

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/v1/export-all")
@PreAuthorize("@accessChecker.isIT(authentication)")
public ResponseEntity<?> exportAllToXml(Principal principal,
```

The @PreAuthorize part is what I'm adding everywhere now.

As these methods are scattered across different controllers it's hard for me to check if I added proper security annotations to every method and didn't miss any.

What I would like to know is if there is some kind of way to make spring list every known URL + how that url is secured. I want to use this as a check to see if I got everything right and to check every now and then if nobody forgot to add security on new methods.

When I start my app, spring logs every known URL so I know it must have that data somewhere hidden away in an internal class. Also when I put a breakpoint in the spring security filters I can see a variable that contains the expression I used to configure security, but only for the URL I'm navigating to, not for all of them.

I'm sure some internal class or turning on a specific logging level will contain all the data I need but I can't find it :) Any help?

Comment: Spring Security's Method Security is not made for controller methods, you should use it only on business classes. So AFAIK there is no coupling of Spring MVC controller methods and Spring Security's Method Security.

Comment: As a work-around you could collect all controller methods and all methods anotated with `@PreAuthorize` (there is a Spring util class for that). Then you can remove all matching methods from the list of controller methods, so that the list only contains non secured methods. I'm not familiar with Spring MVC and don't know an easy way to calculate the URLs for the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks dur for the suggestions. I think that @PreAuthorize on individual methods makes it less likely to forget to add security to new methods on Controllers (rather than managing the security for urls in a central place).

Eventually I went for the workaround you suggested, reading data from annotations and puzzling the required information together manually.

Here is the class I eventually conjured up that lists all the mapped paths it can gather from annotations and checks if there is a PreAuthorize annotation on it as well. It's not very general but I wanted to post it anyway, maybe someone has some use for it.

```
public class SecurityValidationUtility {

    public static void outputSecurityInfo(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {

        for (String beanName : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

            Object obj = context.getBean(beanName);
            Class<?> objClz = obj.getClass();
            if (objClz.getAnnotation(Controller.class) != null || objClz.getAnnotation(RestController.class) != null) {

                List<Method> candidateMethods = Arrays.stream(objClz.getDeclaredMethods())
                        .filter(SecurityValidationUtility::isRequestDeclaration)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                for (Method m : candidateMethods) {

                    String url = readUrlFromControllerAnnotation(objClz) + readUrlFromMethodAnnotation(m);

                    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(url)) {
                        if (!m.isAnnotationPresent(PreAuthorize.class)) {
                            System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(url, 100, ' ') + ": No Security Configured!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(url, 100, ' ') + ": " + m.getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class).value());
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String readUrlFromControllerAnnotation(Class<?> controllerClass) {
        if (controllerClass.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            String[] values = controllerClass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value();
            if (values.length > 0) {
                return values[0];
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static boolean isRequestDeclaration(Method m) {
        return m.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)
                || m.isAnnotationPresent(PostMapping.class)
                || m.isAnnotationPresent(DeleteMapping.class)
                || m.isAnnotationPresent(PutMapping.class)
                || m.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class);
    }

    private static String readUrlFromMethodAnnotation(Method m) {

        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
            GetMapping annotation = m.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
            return getAnnotationValue(annotation.value(), annotation.path()) + " - GET";
        } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(PostMapping.class)) {
            PostMapping annotation = m.getAnnotation(PostMapping.class);
            return getAnnotationValue(annotation.value(), annotation.path()) + " - POST";
        } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(DeleteMapping.class)) {
            DeleteMapping annotation = m.getAnnotation(DeleteMapping.class);
            return getAnnotationValue(annotation.value(), annotation.path()) + " - DELETE";
        } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(PutMapping.class)) {
            PutMapping annotation = m.getAnnotation(PutMapping.class);
            return getAnnotationValue(annotation.value(), annotation.path()) + " - PUT";
        } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            RequestMapping requestMapping = m.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

            RequestMethod[] method = requestMapping.method();

            if (method.length > 0) {
                String url = getAnnotationValue(requestMapping.value(), requestMapping.path());
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(url)) {
                    return " - " + method[0].name();
                } else {
                    return url + " - " + method[0].name();
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    private static String getAnnotationValue(String[] value, String[] path) {
        if (value.length > 0) {
            return value[0];
        }

        if(path.length > 0) {
            return path[0];
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

The class needs an application context to work on. I'm using spring boot so I plugged it in in the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplication(Application.class).run(args);
        SecurityValidationUtility.outputSecurityInfo(context);
    }
}
```